# Is there a way to remove the admin panel logout timer?

Tags: craft3

Having to log in again every few minutes while on a local development environment significantly slows your workflow.

Comment: Yes it is but I'm not sure if you really want to remove it since you'll just lose your state and need a page refresh to login again. So it won't speed up anything

Comment: There is a `userSessionDuration` config setting https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#usersessionduration let me know if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duration of the session can be extended via `userSessionDuration` in your [Configuration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#usersessionduration)

```php
'userSessionDuration' => 7200
```